# Валидация телефона вместе с маской формы

Tags: jquery

Использую плагины:

- для валидации [jquery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)
- для маски [masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#license)

И есть простейшая форма с полем телефона:

```js
$('form').validate();
$('.js-phone').mask("+7(999)999-9999", {autoclear: false});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
  
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="text" class="js-phone" name="ph" placeholder="Номер телефона" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-minlength="10" data-msg="Введите номер телефона">
  </label>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Проблема в том, что ошибка заполнения высвечивается только при пустом поле, но если ввести хотя бы 1 число, то форма становится уже валидной.

**Вопрос**: как можно совместить эти 2 плагина, чтобы отправка (исчезание предупреждения) происходила только после корректного заполнения формы телефона, чтобы хотя бы срабатывало `data-rule-minlength="10"` (т.е. должны быть введены как минимум 10 цифр)? При чем таких форм на странице несколько и каждого поля с телефоном свой `name`, т.е. `name="ph1"` `name="ph2"`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод **validate()** позволяет использовать как существующие правила ([rules](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)), так и создавать свои. Поэтому проблему решить можно, например, таким [способом](https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/490k3jav/12/):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkMask", function(value, element) {
     return /\+\d{1}\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}/g.test(value); 
});

$('form').validate({
  rules: {
    ph: {
      checkMask: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    ph: {
      checkMask: "Введите полный номер телефона"
    }
  }
});
$('.js-phone').mask("+7(999)999-9999", {autoclear: false});
```

Если нужно применить для класса, то код будет [такой](https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/490k3jav/14/):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkMask", function(value, element) {
    return /\+\d{1}\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}/g.test(value); 
});

$('form').validate();

$.validator.addClassRules({
    'js-phone': {
        checkMask: true
    }
});

$('.js-phone').mask("+7(999)999-9999", {autoclear: false});
```

Comment: `ph:` это `name` же? а если универсальней на класс как-то можно повесить? А то таких полей с телефоном много и везде разный `name`

Comment: ph - это name, если для класса нужно применить - используется метод $.validator.addClassRules(). Отредактировала свой ответ и для этого случая

Comment: Спасибо! Кстати нашла еще плюшку `data-rule-checkMask="true" or data-rule-checkMask="codeText"` инлайн прописать в html