# Проверка, чтобы все числа номера телефона были не одинаковые

Tags: javascript, jquery

[В продолжение своего вопроса о маске телефона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682481/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B) возник еще один вопрос.

Как можно усовершенствовать код ( регулярное выражение), чтобы НЕ было возможности ввести все цифры одинаковыми? Т.е. Если пользователь вводит номер `+7(111)111-1111` должна появляться ошибка, но если например так: `+7(111)111-1112`, то все отлично.

```js
$('form').validate();
$('.js-phone').mask("+7(999)999-9999", {autoclear: false});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkMask", function(value, element) {
  return /\+\d{1}\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}/g.test(value); 
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
  
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="text" class="js-phone" name="ph" placeholder="Номер телефона" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-minlength="10" data-msg="Введите номер телефона" data-rule-checkMask="true">
  </label>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: каким-нибудь replace с регуляркой заменить все не числа в строке на пустоту, а затем организовать цикл с посимвольным сравнением (кроме первой семерки)... т.е. последние 10.... и если все равны - выдавать сообщение.

Comment: а почему нельзя ввести все одинаковые цифры?

Comment: А вдруг реальный номер есть со всеми одинаковыми цифрами?

Comment: @Visman с Мавритании теперь один номер и с Монтенегро будет недоступен для сайта :D

Comment: @Grundy, я вот тоже задаю такой вопрос, но ....

Comment: @Grundy видимо заказчик думает, что таким образом защищаются от фальсифицированного номера)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну да, или от владельцев золотых номеров :-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, заказчик на самом деле ни о чем вообще не думает, просто выделывается )

Comment: @HamSter а код страны берется в учет на проверку одинаковости? или речь идет о последних 7-ми цифрах?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, о последних без +7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не уверен, что можно обойтись одним регулярным выражением, но можно добавить второе регулярное выражение, в котором проверить, что все цифры одинаковые.

Для этого можно воспользоваться возможностью проверять уже найденные группы например:

```
/\+\d\((\d){3}\)\1{3}-\1{4}/g
```

Пример:

```js
$('form').validate();
$('.js-phone').mask("+7(999)999-9999", {
  autoclear: false
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkMask", function(value, element) {
  return /\+\d{1}\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}/g.test(value) &&
    !/\+\d\((\d){3}\)\1{3}-\1{4}/g.test(value);
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <label>
    <input type="text" class="js-phone" name="ph" placeholder="Номер телефона" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-minlength="10" data-msg="Введите номер телефона" data-rule-checkMask="true">
  </label>

  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Круто, просто! Спасибо!

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, очень полезно ;-)

Comment: а как изменить маску на такую +9 999 999-99-99 и использовать в нескольких формах, то есть есть 2-3 формы на сайте, и в каждой форме есть поля телефон

Comment: @mat, надо поменять маску  в вызове `.mask`. Этот вызов применяется ко всем выбранным элементам, в данном случае с классом js-phone.

Comment: будут ли какие-то проблемы, если форма после скриптов? сейчас у меня не работает.. также можно изменить маску на +9 999 999-99-99.. в таком маске при валидном вводе номера телефона.. все равно пишет ошибка

Comment: @mat, задай отдельный вопрос [ask] сейчас непонятно какой у тебя код, какую ошибку ты получаешь и что хочешь в итоге